# Finding more flexible 'chart-to-code' software

Tags: software-rec, charts

I'm looking for suggestions of a new software development tool for any object-oriented development language 
e.g. C++ , C# , VB etc.

Here's some examples of some software coding:

[image]

[image]

I'm looking for a piece of software along the lines of the following:

- Has an interface that the user can drag "diagram" such as the rectangle and the rhombus you see in the attachments
- The user can type down the code of a programming language into the diagrams, then the user can use lines to link these diagrams
- After the diagrams are linked, the software can automatically "read" the chart and convert these diagrams into code that is the same as what today's programmers currently type on their own

The concept is basically converting flow charts to code, but different from software like [LabVIEW](http://www.ni.com/labview/) that uses "pre-coded icons".

It's also different from what any other GUI component coding software (like [Xcode](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/)) does.

Does anyone know of any software like this?

Comment: Have you looked into Microsoft Visio? I have written several flow charts in this program and has done a decent job.

Comment: You know that your username will make it more difficult to direct replies at you, right?

Comment: Thank you so much for the notice about the name (sıɔuɐɹℲ). I used gmail to login and it took all info from there automagically. I have changed it. Again, my sincere thanks. - Any thoughts on some software can do what I ask above?